# Guava's `Files#write` doesn't write last empty line?

Tags: java, file-io, guava

I have a simple method which reads a file, modifies some lines based on a condition, and then writes the modified string back to the same file. The outline is as follows:

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import static java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset;

static final DIR = ;
String enforceVerbTag(String inputfilename) {
    String predictedTags = Files.toString(new File(DIR, inputfilename),
                                          defaultCharset());
    String[] lines = predictedTags.split("\\r?\\n");
    List<String> modifiedLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] fields = line.split("\\t");
        if (mycondition)
            fields[1] = "VB";
        String modifiedLine = Joiner.on('\t').join(fields);
        modifiedLines.add(modifiedLine);
    }
    modifiedLines.add("");
    Files.write(Joiner.on('\n').join(modifiedLines),
                new File(DIR, inputfilename),
                defaultCharset());
}
```

The input file has an empty last line, and I want the output file to retain that. But in spite of `modifiedLines.add("")` followed by joining on `\n`, the output file doesn't have that last empty line. As far as I know, Guava's `Files#write` doesn't do any trimming, so why does this happen?

I know there are many other ways of writing that last empty line. But I would like to know what is going wrong with *this* method.

Comment: Why the downvote? My question may seem stupid to some, but I believe many people can benefit from (i) my mistake, and more importantly, (ii) the answer/explanation given by @maaartinus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple: The joiner joins, and you get a string without terminating `'\n'`.

```
first \n
second \n
third (no \n)
```

Then you add an empty String, and it just makes the last line terminated:

```
first \n
second \n
third \n
(nothing) (no \n)
```

You must add another `""` to get an empty line.

```
first \n
second \n
third \n
(nothing) \n
(nothing) (no \n)
```

---

You could use a function appending newline instead of the joiner, but this is longer (at least with Java < 8) and slower due to extraneous string creation.

Comment: All these years, and I always thought adding a `\n` would give me a visible empty line at the end. It's weird how many lines of code one can write before having to face some of the simplest facts!

Comment: I don't understand why this is the correct answer. On your example, you have two empty lines `\n
(nothing) \n
(nothing)`

Comment: @rds No. The `\n` belongs to the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, everything works for me. These tests pass with JDK7 and Guava 12.0.1

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class GuavaTests {
    @Test
    public void testJoiner()  {
        assertEquals("a\nb", Joiner.on('\n').join(ImmutableList.of("a", "b")));
        assertEquals("a\nb\n", Joiner.on('\n').join(ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "")));
    }

    public void testFilesWrite() throws IOException {
        File f = new File("tests.txt");
        final String content="a\nb\n";
        Files.write(content, f, Charset.defaultCharset());
        assertEquals(content.length(), f.length());
    }
}
```

The text files contains 3 lines:

```
a
b
(empty)
```

Comment: Your test is fine, but no. There are exactly two `\n` in your text, which means two terminated lines and nothing more. The common understanding is that an empty line at EOF looks like `\n\n` (e.g., the whole text would be `a\nb\n\n`).

Comment: Yes, I suppose we don't define "empty line" the same way. For me "abc" is a text file with one line "abc\n" is a text file with two lines (one with text, one empty), and "abc\n\n" is a text file with two empty lines. By the way, that's how TextWrangler, TextMate and IntelliJ count lines.

Comment: You consider `\n` to be a line separator and this makes sense. As I'm using git which complains about missing `\n` on the last line, I stick with its definition. I tried to count lines using `/usr/bin/wc -l` and it claims that `a\nb` is a single line. ;) Yet another possibility.